# Making a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game thru a 2D array in java:

Tags: java, arrays

I have made an array using the code below.

I am having trouble looping the game to continually ask the user for their input until the user wins.

So far, the output '**X**' is placed under the user's coordinate choice, but the program continues to place '**X**' in all the coordinates below the indicated one.

Is there a way to make the game re-ask the question after getting the user's first input?

Also, is it possible to have the '**X**' output in only the specified coordinate?

Any suggestions on making my program better /solving these problems would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Output the Tic Tac Toe playing field, just an empty one to show the users the game...
    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    int y = 0;
    boolean op = true;


    String[][] myArray = new String[rows][columns];
    //Create for-loop that will print out column numbers in order and have the correct spacing
    for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.print(y + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Create nested for-loop that will add the dots for the spaces into the 2D arrays 
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        System.out.print(x + 1);//print out the row numbers,start @1
        for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
            myArray[x][y] = "  " + "." + " ";
            System.out.print(myArray[x][y]);
        }//nested-for loop; columns
        System.out.println("");
    }//close Rows for-loop

    //Set up a scanner object that will read the user's input and greet them
    System.out.println("");
    Scanner inReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello user :) Please enter the move you would like to make (2 numbers [from 1 to 3] seperated by a space)");
    //char userMo = inReader.next().charAt(0);

    int userMoveA = inReader.nextInt();
    int userMoveA1 = inReader.nextInt();

    System.out.println(" ");
    //Create an if statement that prints out the possible values of X
    //

    for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.print(y + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Create nested for-loop that will add the dots for the spaces into the 2D arrays 
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        System.out.print(x + 1);//print out the row numbers,start @1
        for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) {

            myArray[x][y] = "  " + "." + " ";
            System.out.print(myArray[x][y]);

            if (userMoveA >= 0 && userMoveA <= 3 && userMoveA1 >= 0 && userMoveA1 <= 3) {
                System.out.println(myArray[userMoveA][userMoveA1] = "x");
            }


        }//nested-for loop; columns
        System.out.println("");
    }//close Rows for-loop


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe this line please:
 System.out.println(myArray[userMoveA][userMoveA1] = "x");

Comment: yes! this line is to print the 'x' into the tictactoe grid to the specified row and column the user inputted respectively

Comment: I know but why just x, should user choose from x or y, why you put it static in the code.

Comment: 'x' sort of represents the players game piece.. i am only required to give them one option, so x is like a set output.. hope that clarifies it a bit more

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is : "I am having trouble looping the game to continually ask the user for their input until the user wins." In other words "I am having trouble looping the game to continually ask the user for their input until  a stop criteria is met". I would suggest to post a [MCVE] that tries to do just that. Omit all the rest.  It will be much easier and faster to help you. (Additional benefit: doing so you will most likely solve it yourself)